Accessing Private Subnet RDS in AWS from my local machine
I created a VPC with the private subnet.
I created a RDS MySQL Instance.
I wanted to keep my RDS secure so I put it into private subnet and set Publicly Accessible flag to false.
The problem is, now I can't connect my RDS from MySQL Workbench.
I considered the following examples.

Creating an EC2 instance as a bastion host and then setting an SHH tunnel seems unnecessarily complex and it costs money since we need to create an EC2 instance.
Using AWS VPN Client Service is easier but it costs even more money.

If there are any others, what are the best practices for accessing private subnet RDS with cost efficient options?

Nope, you'll need to do one of those. The whole idea of a private subnet is to prevent direct access from the Internet. If you want it in the private subnet, you need to provide a way to access it. Alternatively, you could put it in a public subnet and be very careful about your Security Group configuration.

Okay, thanks for the answer. Then I will probably go with the public subnet.
